# Class property becomes a union instead of being discriminated by Generic Type

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to define property type based on generic type.

```
    interface Option<T> {
        text: string
        value: T
    }
    
    class MultiSelect<T, TGroup extends boolean = false> {
        public groups: TGroup;
        public options: TGroup extends true ? { group: Option<T> } : Option<T>
    
        constructor(groups: TGroup, options: TGroup extends true ? { group: Option<T> } : Option<T>) {
            this.groups = groups
            this.options = options
        }
    
        public get allOptions(): Option<T> {
            return this.groups ? this.options.group : this.options
        }
    }
```

But `this.options` is not being discriminated by `TGroup` and instead becomes a union `Option<T> | { group: Option<T>; }`

Therefore when trying to access this.optoin.group from within ternary it errors

```
Property 'group' does not exist on type 'Option<T> | { group: Option<T>; }'.
  Property 'group' does not exist on type 'Option<T>'
```

Here is [Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPIAczAPYgDwAqAfMgN4BQyVykAHmAFzIDOYUoA5pdQG5wA2AVwhMC5AL7lyCfnGbNkAWUH8sAZQj8ICMIQA0yAgHEo2QemQR6EEABMFAI2zYtcEMgC8yeP2YQSFNTI6IIO-MAIyBym5syiJmboANzcVCFhEcjYmDggcYYJ5pbWdgpswsgA-GRRMehMGFi4hCTiyA05zcRSQQi4rFCCOthQABTRifnGdQbZTXnxdcWQpTSDKNWktYkd8y3Ibbu5LQCUZKlBNAAWwMwAdBOxntuxF0FgN-dzuQpe3-0XSQXdLhSIcCBgZACfiNH6jE5HLoBN7UKAQwRQdwfW4POoKarYr6dPK4xLta44-55QESbhAA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript type discrimination requires that the types that you want to discriminate between be defined in a union. You can have TS discriminate here if you combine the `groups` and `options` properties into a single type and then create a union of the two variations.

```
interface Option<T> {
    text: string
    value: T
}

type SelectOptions<T> = {
    groups: false
    options: Option<T>
} | {
    groups: true
    options: {
        group: Option<T>
    }
}

class MultiSelect<T> {
    private selectOptions: SelectOptions<T>

    constructor(selectOptions: SelectOptions<T>) {
        this.selectOptions = selectOptions
    }

    public get allOptions(): Option<T> {
        return this.selectOptions.groups ? this.selectOptions.options.group : this.selectOptions.options
    }
}
```

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPIAczAPYgDwAqAfMgN4BQyVykAHmAFzIDOYUoA5pdQG5wA2AVwhMC5AL7lyYAJ7oUAZQj8ICMBiy5mhEgF4y3KhyjZB6Zk3j9mEQ8myYcIC2ke4dE5AB8D1ZMdNzJjZhOwdNZyYKPz8AsyYNJw8-SUlyBH44ZmZkAFlBfiwlFTUdX2p0dj5IFmVVdTdI5GL6xK0POwQtELVsKAAKGxKGiJcWtTbnHQBKcpiaAAtgZgA6IdbGnP11ic27NL90QQAjfmAEfwgwZAF%20SeZ%206YTGsuj55CgrwSgQReW1uq7UYrOLmZAAfj%20qx2Iycq3CcJBJjMyGCS2hgNhWhWCK0%20wk3CAA)